# Suspend master CMake when using ExternalProject

Tags: cmake

I use [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) in my `CMakeLists.txt` as follows:

```
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(eigen_build
  SOURCE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/${EIGEN_DIR}
  # CONFIGURE_COMMAND cmake
  CMAKE_ARGS
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release
)
```

This works fine when building on a PC, but when building on a resource-limited target with `cmake -j8`, having two active `make` instances with 8 tasks each causes the build to often fail with out of memory conditions.

One workaround I have tried is:

```
# Find out host architecture
execute_process(COMMAND
  dpkg-architecture
    -qDEB_HOST_ARCH
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE
    CMAKE_DEB_HOST_ARCH
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)

# If we are building on arm64 then limit subprocesses to 2
if(${CMAKE_DEB_HOST_ARCH} MATCHES "arm64")
  set(NUM_SUB_PROCESSES 2)
else()
  set(NUM_SUB_PROCESSES 8)
endif()
message("Building library with ${NUM_SUB_PROCESSES} subprocess(es)")

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(eigen_build
  SOURCE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/${EIGEN_DIR}
  # CONFIGURE_COMMAND cmake
  CMAKE_ARGS
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release
  BUILD_COMMAND make -j${NUM_SUB_PROCESSES}
  INSTALL_COMMAND make install -j${NUM_SUB_PROCESSES}
)
```

This appears to work, but there is still perhaps a risk of occasional failure, plus it makes the sub-build really slow resulting in other tasks wait on completion; building the target separately is of course a manual workaround. However, ideally I would like some option to suspend all parent tasks while this `ExternalProject` is building; is there some way to do this? (Note, I cannot easily fiddle with dependencies as this is just one small part of a 100+ module build system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a Makefile generator you should try to use the load option `-l` to limit the number of jobs instead of using the jobs number `-j` (RTFM ;) )

ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parallel

Comment: That looks useful; I can use [`ProcessorCount()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ProcessorCount.html) to get the number of cores, then pass that to `-l`.